# Dailymotion "broke" HTTPS with video thumbnail (Chrome warning)

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, dailymotion-api, mixed-content

I have an embed dailymotion video inside a web page. I use the code below to display it. This code call the preview picture of the video through HTTP instead of HTTPS whereas web page domain is on HTTPS.

API call is well sent with HTTPS protocol :

```
document.location.protocol
```

Due to this, all ressources into the web page are not sent through HTTPS and Chrome display a warning on the SSL certificate.

```
<script>
// Dailymotion SDK 
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//api.dmcdn.net/all.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
}());
window.dmAsyncInit = function()
{
    var player = DM.player("player", {video: "x254e00", width: "480", height: "270"});
    player.addEventListener("play", function(e)
    {
        $('.video_layer').hide();
    });
};
```

Do you have an idea, how to force this HTTPS call for picture preview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug when requesting thumbnails that caused them not being passed over https. It has now been fixed. 
Now talking about the embed: currently some resources inside the Dailymotion embed are loaded in HTTP, but this remains local to the Dailymotion iframe, your other resources in the page are not affected and continue to be sent through HTTPS.